# Nano's find and replace in Vim?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, nano

Vim's find and replace is very powerful and very useful however sometimes I don't want that power - adding backslashes can be a drag. Sometimes, I just want to find and replace exactly across a whole document. No patterns. No magic.

Nano's find/replace is exactly what I want, pretty much.

Is there a plugin or command that will provide me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then disable the magic for that search -- `/\V(nothing)+ is magic* but backslash`.  See `:help magic`.  This is actually what the Search dialog in gvim does by default.

Comment: I think you mean `/\V` which is very nomagic, not `/\v` which is very magic.

Comment: Erm.. I didn't know it was *actually* called magic... huh. Anyway, that's perfect - many thanks!